Prevent css color-scheme to be applied to an element
On a page there is the css rule : :root{color-scheme: dark;}
In that page, I want to prevent a specific element to not be affected by this css rule.
I try these rules on the specific element color-scheme: normal; or color-scheme: only light; but it's not working.
You could find a testing example of my problem bellow, where I want <h1> to be always in light mode (ie. text color always black)
How I could do that ?


let root = document.querySelector(":root");
let button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  root.classList.toggle("light");
});
:root {
  color-scheme: dark;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  place-items: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
  width: 300px;
}
.only-light {
  color-scheme: normal;
}

.light {
  color-scheme: light;
}
<h1 class="only-light">Heading 1</h1>

<button>
  Toggle Color
</button>




Did you check out the only value? documentation - "Forbids the user agent from overriding the color scheme for the element."

Yes, I test it on this codepen: https://codepen.io/NathanBruet/pen/yLmeEeo
But it's not working neither

FWIW: If you inspect the heading, in the codepen posted in the comments, you can see the only light has priority, though the color changes when clicking the button

What behavior are you expecting ? since you didn't precise any color in your style ?

I think you should read the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme. color-scheme doesn't defines or overrides a color, look at the examples, understand it

@VincentDecaux - No, but the browser does - You can clearly see the color switching from white to black if you turn on the computed styles even when the doc states that using only forbids this

Yes, but the color is not depending on color-scheme, read the doc. Color will inherit from the color-scheme, so you can't control it.

color is inherited so you cannot really do this since the h1 will (in all the cases) inherit the color that changes with color-scheme
Either set the color of the h1 explicitly or don't set color-scheme on the :root element
